# why my Grouped tableView`s cell.backgroundView is nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is my code , it is very sample.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        _userView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];

        _userView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        [self addSubview:_userView];


        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 420) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

        _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;



        [self addSubview:_tableView];

//        _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;


    }
    return self;
}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    return 3;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return 2;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"aaa"];

    if (!cell.backgroundView) {
        NSLog(@"wrong");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

My table is grouped , the doc of Apple says that :
the cell.background : // Default is nil for cells in UITableViewStylePlain, and non-nil for UITableViewStyleGrouped. The 'backgroundView' will be added as a subview behind all other views.

but my cell.backgroundView = nil.

anyone help , thank you.

Comment: Are you subclassing `UITableViewCell`? Does your table appear as a grouped table? Also, are you loading the view controller from a .xib?

Comment: @sooper my view subclassing UIView , I use UITableViewCell not my CustomCell. it appear as a grouped table . I do not use .xib